# Image attachment in php fails to be sent?

Tags: php

The code below works perfectly well when I change the attached file to an html file,but when I change the attached file to an image i.e. screenshot.png it fails to send the message.

```
<?php
    $file_path = "screenshot.png"; // server path where file is placed
    $file_path_type = "image/png"; // File Type
    $file_path_name = "screenshot.png"; // this file name will be used at reciever end 

    $from = "xyz@gmail.com"; // E-mail address of sender
    $to = "abc@gmail.com"; // E-mail address of reciever
    $subject = "Please check the Attachment."; // Subject of email
    $message = "This is the message body.&lt;br&gt;&lt;br&gt;Thank You!&lt;br&gt;&lt;a href='http://7tech.co.in'&gt;7tech.co.in Team&lt;/a&gt;"; 

    $headers = "From: ".$from; 

    $file = fopen($file_path,'rb');
    $data = fread($file,filesize($file_path));
    fclose($file); 

    $rand = md5(time());
    $mime_boundary = "==Multipart_Boundary_x{$rand}x"; 

    $headers .= "\nMIME-Version: 1.0\n" .
    "Content-Type: multipart/mixed;\n" .
    " boundary=\"{$mime_boundary}\""; 

    $message .= "This is a multi-part message in MIME format.\n\n" .
    "--{$mime_boundary}\n" .
    "Content-Type:text/html; charset=\"iso-8859-1\"\n" .
    "Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit\n\n" .
    $message .= "\n\n"; 

    $data = chunk_split(base64_encode($data)); 

    $message .= "--{$mime_boundary}\n" .
    "Content-Type: {$file_path_type};\n" .
    " name=\"{$file_path_name}\"\n" .
    "Content-Disposition: attachment;\n" .
    " filename=\"{$file_path_name}\"\n" .
    "Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64\n\n" .
    $data .= "\n\n" .
    "--{$mime_boundary}--\n";  

    if(@mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers)) {
    echo "File send!";

    } else {
    echo 'Failed';
    }
    ?>
```

Can you guys point out the error.I've tried to cahnge content type too at 1-2 places but it wasn't working.Am I missing anything?

Comment: try replacing `\n` with `\r\n` in whole script

Comment: Sigh. Why does everyone go to so much effort to write code to send email attachments in php when classes like phpMailer and Swiftmailer exist. They're free, open source, secure, and you can do the whole thing in three lines of code. And most importantly, they work brilliantly out of the box, without you having to mess around with all that base64 and mime boundary stuff. Seriously, just throw away all that code, and download phpMailer. You'll thank me for it.

Answer (score 0):

It can occur due to a misconfiguration in your webserver. By changing the allowed filesize, maybe it will work.